# How to use concat and chr function in a django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset, concatenation

I'm trying something like this:

```py
my_field=Concat(
                (chr(65) + F("foo")),
                F("bar") + Value(1),
                output_field=CharField(),
            )
```

But I got this error: `invalid input syntax for integer: "A"`

`foo` and `bar` return a integer and I expect "A1, A2, B1, B2, B3, C1, ..." like a result.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Concat('A', F('foo'), ',A', F('bar'))` then?

Comment: Hey @WillemVanOnsem thanks. But I need of the chr, because I want: A1, B1, C1,... 'foo' is a integer.